# Registering as a sole trader and documentation needed - From Portugal to United Kingdom

Tags: united-kingdom, freelance, identification, europe

I am currently living in Portugal and goin to move to the UK (Scotland) tomorrow. 
My boyfriend found a job there, so his company will be taking care of most of the needed paperwork, but I will have to work as a freelancer.

In order to set up as a sole trader it seems that I have to follow the instructions I found here https://www.gov.uk/set-up-sole-trader, but I find myself with some doubts. 
A lot of the information I find online is for people outside the EU and need Visas.

I will need a national insurance number right? Where should I go to request one as a new UK resident?

It seems that when applying for a Biometric Residence Permit, a national insurance number would be assigned to me, but as a EU citizen can I apply for a Biometric Residence Permit?

If I cannot obtain a Biometric Residence Permit, what type of UK identification can I get?

Comment: You can get your accountancy firm to do most of leg work, that's what I did. And you can *TRY* for a temporary NIN...

Answer (score 1):

Nobody cares where you currently live - the question is what your nationality is. Are you a UK citizen, or a EU citizen?

To get the NI number, assuming you are a EU citizen: Call the numbers given at https://www.gov.uk/apply-national-insurance-number . You don't have and you don't need a "Biometric Residence Permit" if you have a EU passport. You have to be in the UK to apply, but you will get a number without any problems.

You might consider starting a Limited Liability Company which has some tax advantages compared to being a sole trader, especially if you make more than about £40,000 a year. Check that out at http://companieshouse.gov.uk .